# Смещается блок который не должен смещаться

Tags: javascript, html, css

При нажатии на Lorem1 смещается блок Lorem2, нужно чтобы блок Lorem2 оставался на месте, в чем моя ошибка?

```js
One.onclick = function(){
  let display = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('blockOne')).display;
  if (display == "none"){
      document.getElementById('blockOne').style.display = "block";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('blockOne').style.display = "none";
  }
}

Two.onclick = function(){
  let display = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('blockTwo')).display;
  if (display == "none"){
      document.getElementById('blockTwo').style.display = "block";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('blockTwo').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#blockTwo{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
#Two{
  font-size: 50px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
 left: 250px;
}
#blockOne{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
#One{
  font-size: 50px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
 
}
```

```html
<button id="One">Lorem1</button>
    <div id="blockOne">Что то 1</div>
 <button id="Two">Lorem2</button>
    <div id="blockTwo">Что то 2</div>
```

Comment: button - это строчно-блочный элемент, div - это блочный элемент.
Блочный элемент всегда начинается с новой строки.
Строчные элементы следуют друг за другом.
Пока блочные элемент скрыты, строчные идут друг за другом, когда появляется блочный - он появляется на новой строке и так как он находится между строчными он их разлучает ((((

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex Так где бы не находился lorem1 он всегда будет сдвигать lorem2, хоть в одной строке хоть в углу экрана и вот мне не понятно, почему именно так

Comment: что тебе не понятно? https://jsfiddle.net/7qvaz183/

Comment: я вроде доступно объяснил

Comment: лежат себе две кнопочки рядом никого не трогают и тут бац между ними появляется огромный блок на всю ширину экрана, куда правой кнопочке деваться?

Comment: и если ты думал, что относительное позиционирование спасёт их от разлуки, то ты ошибался, потому что относительное  позиционирование не вынимает элемент из потока.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex вы меня не слышите, я вам говорю, что даже если `One` и `blockOne` Находятся с права сверху, а `Two` и `blockTwo` Слева сверху, то блок `One` при нажатии сдвинет `Two`

Comment: О боже, какая разница что где визуально находится, посмотри как расположены элементы в html-документе, прочитай ещё раз комментарии и прозрей уже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если чуть чуть переделать вёрстку добавить flexbox и указать хоть какую то ширину то всё выглядит прилично

```js
One.onclick = function() {
  let display = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('blockOne')).display;
  if (display == "none") {
    document.getElementById('blockOne').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('blockOne').style.display = "none";
  }
}

Two.onclick = function() {
  let display = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('blockTwo')).display;
  if (display == "none") {
    document.getElementById('blockTwo').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('blockTwo').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}

#blockOne {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

#blockTwo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <button id="One">Lorem1</button>
    <div id="blockOne">Что то 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <button id="Two">Lorem2</button>
    <div id="blockTwo">Что то 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка в неверном использовании свойства `position`. Вам нужно подтянуть матчасть. Эта информация общедоступна и пересказывать ее здесь нет смысла.

Comment: а почему в position ? он ведь не понимает за display:block ... и как ведут себя блочные элементы . Там position вообще у всех можно убрать, ничего не поменяется

Comment: @BlackStar1991, про элементы это да, но тут больше объяснять. ) И кстати речь не об убрать `position`, а речь об использовать правильно.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Если убрать position то как мне поставить что то в середине экрана, а что то с правого края? Без этого не как, но на каком бы расстоянии они не были, происходит такая канитель

Comment: @AndreyFedorov В чем конкретно я не правильно использую свойство position ? Если вас смущает что оно relative, то это требуется чтобы разместить в тех участках экрана, где нужно

Comment: @user362586 ну т.е. документацию гуглить вы не хотите?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov я такое разве писал? или говорил?

Comment: @user362586 не обижайтесь, просто когда прочтете документацию сразу поймете в чем конкретно ошибка в использовании `position`

Comment: @AndreyFedorov и так, я прочитал пару десятков раз документацию и понял в чем  заключается моя ошибка, нужно было просто вместо `relative` поставить `absolute`, спасибо вам что хоть не очень приятным путем, но обучили меня, я вам серьезно благодарен :)

Comment: @user362586 на здоровье. )))